# Proving a value is a root of a polynomial other than $f(x)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

$$4x^4-16x^3+115x^2+4x-29=0$$

has roots: $$\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$$

Show that $2-5i$ is a root of the equation.

This to me was simply sub $f(2-5i)$ and see if it equaled zero, which it did. However since this had to be done by hand, it took a while and was rather tedious for only 3 marks. I was wondering if there was any other way this could be done out of pure curiosity, or I can say it's 'just of of those questions'.

Comment: It is easy to factorise it as $(2x-1)(2x+1)(x^2-4x+29)$ and to see that the roots of the quadratic are $2\pm5i$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complex roots have to appear with their conjugates.  So $2+5i$ also has to be a root.  The quadratic polynomial for these 2 roots is $x^2-4x+29$.  So you can check to see whether this quadratic is a factor of the given polynomial, either by determining other factors or direct division.

Comment: Is it enough to state: if $2-5i$ is a factor, then $x^2-4x+29$ must divide $f(x)$ completely?

Comment: Yes, that works.